# When recursing in prolog, can one access variables from n amount of levels up?

Tags: recursion, prolog

To clarify what I mean, lets take this recursing example:

```
statement([]). 
statement([A|B]):- A, statement(B).
```

The head, A is check by the rules my rules, and the tail B is sent to be recursed, which then becomes the head of level 2. When it recurses and is at the second level, how can I access the previous A? Am I thinking about it all wrong? If any clarification is needed please ask and I will do so. Thanks in advance.

What I am suppose to be testing for(type checker):

```
String s; int i; i = s.length(); // OK
```

or

```
String s; int i; s = i.length(); // fails
```

Comment: What's wrong with passing it as a parameter?  statement(B,A)

Comment: Because I will be sending it a list. I will add what I am suppose to be checking. I will of course take recommendations of a better way of doing this. The only things is I am not sure whether there will be testing with more than what I will show.

Comment: The elements of the list that are passed to statement() are tokens?

Comment: I am actually not sure about tokens. An example could be statement([instance(string, s), instance(int, z), equals(i, method(s, length))]). Hopefully that helps. If not, then I can post it up with a more detailed example.

Comment: As you can see, if I have this in a list, recursing it would end up losing what unifications I had made currently, or at least I assume this is what is suppose to happen.

Comment: You'll need to have a state that gets passed along.  Something like check([A|B],State) :- execute(A,State,NewState),check(B,NewState).

Comment: Hmm, is there a better way that you recommend?

Comment: In Prolog it's always better to keep the most declarative code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to record the previous statements explicitly such that at each iteration you will have access to the previous steps. It is up to you how do you record these statements. One solution would be:

```
statement(L) :- statement(L,[]).
statement([], _). 
statement([A|B], L):- check(A), statement(B,[A|L]).
```

L records the preceding statements (in a reverse order).

Answer (score 0):

Sure.. use the prolog database, assert and retract. This demonstrates it:

```
% Declare the lasthead fact as dynamic, so facts can change
:-dynamic lasthead/1.

% Set a starting value for the first iteration
lasthead(null).

statement([]).
statement([A|B]) :-

    % Show the previous head
    lasthead(LH),
    writeln(['Last head was', LH]),

    % Retract last head. ie. remove from the database
    retract(lasthead(_)),

    % Store the current head in the database
    assertz(lasthead(A)),

    % Recurse around
    statement(B).


?- statement([a,b,c,d,e]).
[Last head was,null]
[Last head was,a]
[Last head was,b]
[Last head was,c]
[Last head was,d]
```

The above example uses retract to ensure there is only once lasthead(X) fact, but you could remove the retract which would ensure having multiple lasthead(X) facts, one for each list item.

You could then access/process multiple lasthead(X) facts using eg. findall(X, lasthead(X), Y), which would give you whichever lasthead(X) values you asserted along the way.

Comment: It might not be an appropriate use of `assertz/1` but I find it annoying when people -1 without any comment.

Comment: I agree - a carefully crafted comment on the answer's problems would have helped the site and it's readers much further. Less than perfect answers give the possibility of comparing and contrasting them with the best ones, helping everybody.